# pre selecting in mui datagrid disables the data grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a mui datagrid which I want to have preselected rows. this is my code:

```
const movieCrewList = movieCrew.map((item) => item.id);
```

```
const [selecteTabledData, setSelectedTableData] = React.useState([]);
```

```
<DataGrid
  rows={crewData}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={5}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
  checkboxSelection
  onSelectionModelChange={(selectionModel) => {
    setSelectedTableData(selectionModel);
  }}
  selectionModel={movieCrewList}
/>
```

It works and I get the pre-selected rows but the problem is I can't select any other rows after that and it looks like the whole table gets disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `selecteTabledData` in the `selectionModel`

```
  selectionModel={selecteTabledData}
```

use useEffect to set the default value in the state

```
const [selecteTabledData, setSelectedTableData] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const movieCrewList = movieCrew.map((item) => item.id);
    setSelectedTableData(movieCrewList)
}, [movieCrew])
```